# Question on Pointer Arithmetic

Tags: pointers, warnings, math

Heyy Everybody!
I am trying to create a memory management system, so that a user can call myMalloc, a method I created.  I have a linked list keeping track of my free memory.  My problem is when I am attempting to find the end of a free bit in my linked list.  I am attempting to add the size of the memory free in that section (which is in the linked list) to the pointer to the front of the free space, like this.

```
void *tailEnd = previousPlace->head_ptr + ((previousPlace->size+1)*(sizeof(int));
```

I was hoping that this would give me a pointer to the end of that segment. However, I keep getting the warning:

"pointer of type 'void*' used in arithmetic"

Is there a better way of doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic uses the size of the underlying type.  If int is 4 bytes:

```
int *p = some_address;
p++;
```

will increment p by 4 bytes.  void can't be used in pointer arithmetic because void has no size associated with.  If you want to do byte-sized arithmetic on void pointers, you need to cast the pointers to a byte-sized type.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *tailEnd = ( int* ) ( previousPlace->head_ptr + ((previousPlace->size+1)*(sizeof(int)) );
```

Comment: Thanks!! And for anyone else referencing this, I should also note that you can cast this back to a void* afterwards if need be.